# Как исправить ошибку об отсутствии агрумента message

Tags: python, discord

```
@bot.command()
async def add_site(ctx, message):
    global all_tegs
    await ctx.send('Введите категорию сайта : ')
    a = await bot.wait_for('message', check=lambda m: m.author == ctx.author)
    if a.content in all_tegs:
        new_dict = {a.content}
        all_tegs.update(new_dict)
        await ctx.send('Введите название сайта')
        new_site = {await bot.wait_for('message', check=lambda m: m.author == ctx.author).content}
        all_tegs.update(new_site)
    else:
        await ctx.send('Введите название сайта')
        new_site = {(await bot.wait_for('message', check=lambda m: m.author == ctx.author).content)}
        all_tegs[a.content].update(new_site)
```

и выводит ошибку

```
raise MissingRequiredArgument(param)
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: message is a required argument that is missing.
```

Comment: Например, добавить message?